# AWS UNLOAD invalid credentials clause

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload data from AWS Redshift to an s3 bucket. The Redshift cluster is additionally password protected. I set up the aws cli to use an appropriate key pair and tested with success. I am able to access the Redshift cluster with DataGrip with my credentials, but now when I try to unload using following script in python3

```
import json
import os
import psycopg2


def run(config_json, sql_query):

    conn = psycopg2.connect(**config_json['db'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = """
        UNLOAD ($${}$$)
        to \'{}\'
        parallel off
        delimiter ','
        allowoverwrite;
        """.format(sql_query, config_json['s3bucket_path_to_file'])
    print("The following UNLOAD query is being run: \n" + query)
    cursor.execute(query)
    print('Completed write to {}'.format(config_json['s3bucket_path_to_file']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'config.json')
    with open(config_path, 'r') as f:
        config = json.loads(f.read())

    query_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'query.sql')
    with open(query_path, 'r') as f:
        query_sql = f.read()

    run(config, query_sql)
```

I get following error

```
psycopg2.InternalError: invalid CREDENTIALS clause
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  invalid CREDENTIALS clause
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     2820791
  location:  aws_credentials_parser.cpp:62
  process:   padbmaster [pid=25330]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

the `config.json` file has the following format:

```
{
  "db": {
    "dbname": "dbname",
    "user": "user1",
    "host": "someip",
    "password": "very secret psw",
    "port": "1111"
  },
  "s3bucket_path_to_file": "s3://bucket-name/path/to/file.csv"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not specified the CREDENTIALS part in your query statement. In order for Redshift to write to your S3 bucket, you need to provide valid credentials that Redshift will use.

You can either specify an `iam_role` OR `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` (and session_token if using temporary credentials).

Comment: As John said, you need to provide Authorization Parameters in the UNLOAD statement, these are the same as for the COPY command and are described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-authorization.html

Comment: I did that and now I get the next problem, just to say that I am on it and when it finally works I will accept this answer.

Comment: It's not `iam_role `, it's `aws_iam_role`